# Threads never seem to get a chance, unless I have a breakpoint

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, locking

I try to make a simple program that does the following:

I have two cranes that take containers off a ship. They put the containers on the quay, where 2/3 trucks pick them up. Cranes can put a maximum of 5 containers on the quay.

The problem is the following: when I don't have breakpoints, the crane threads just pick containers of the ship and put them onto the quay and then the program stops. This is the output every time:

```
Kraan 2 heeft container nummer 1 van het schip gehaald.
Kraan 2 heeft container nummer 1 op de kade geplaatst.
Kraan 1 heeft container nummer 2 van het schip gehaald.
Kraan 1 heeft container nummer 2 op de kade geplaatst.
Kraan 2 heeft container nummer 3 van het schip gehaald.
Kraan 1 heeft container nummer 4 van het schip gehaald.
Kraan 2 heeft container nummer 3 op de kade geplaatst.
Kraan 2 heeft container nummer 5 van het schip gehaald.
Kraan 2 heeft container nummer 5 op de kade geplaatst.
Kraan 1 heeft container nummer 4 op de kade geplaatst.
Kraan 2 heeft container nummer 6 van het schip gehaald.
Kraan 1 heeft container nummer 7 van het schip gehaald.
```

So, the truck threads do not run. When I put a breakpoint in Wagen.VoerWerkzaamhedenUit(), the breakpoint *does* get hit and miraculously the whole program runs till all containers have been processed.

Here's my code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                Schip.LaadContainerOpSchip(i);
            }

            Thread kraan1 = new Thread(new Kraan().VoerWerkzaamhedenUit);
            kraan1.Name = "Kraan 1";
            kraan1.Start();

            Thread kraan2 = new Thread(new Kraan().VoerWerkzaamhedenUit);
            kraan2.Name = "Kraan 2";
            kraan2.Start();

            Thread wagen1 = new Thread(new Wagen().VoerWerkzaamhedenUit);
            wagen1.Name = "Wagen 1";
            wagen1.Start();

            Thread wagen2 = new Thread(new Wagen().VoerWerkzaamhedenUit);
            wagen2.Name = "Wagen 2";
            wagen2.Start();

            kraan1.Join();
            kraan2.Join();
            wagen1.Join();
            wagen2.Join();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

public class Kraan
    {
        private Random random = new Random();

        public void VoerWerkzaamhedenUit()
        {
            while (Schip.HeeftContainers())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 6000));

                int container = Schip.VerwijderContainer();

                if (container != -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} heeft container nummer {1} van het schip gehaald.", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, container);

                    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 6000));

                    Kade.PlaatsContainer(container);

                    Console.WriteLine("{0} heeft container nummer {1} op de kade geplaatst.", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, container);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static class Schip
    {
        private static List<int> containers = new List<int>();

        public static void LaadContainerOpSchip(int container)
        {
            containers.Add(container);
        }

        public static int VerwijderContainer()
        {
            lock (containers)
            {
                int container = -1;

                if (containers.Any())
                {
                    container = containers[0];

                    containers.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                return container;
            }
        }

        public static bool HeeftContainers()
        {
            lock (containers)
            {
                return containers.Any();
            }
        }
    }



public static class Kade
    {
        private static List<int> containers = new List<int>();

        public static void PlaatsContainer(int container)
        {
            lock (containers)
            {
                while (containers.Count == 5)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(containers);
                }

                containers.Add(container);

                Monitor.PulseAll(containers);
            }
        }

        public static int VerwijderContainer()
        {    
            lock (containers)
            {
                while (containers.Count == 0)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(containers);
                }

                int container = -1;

                if (containers.Any())
                {
                    container = containers[0];

                    containers.RemoveAt(0);
                }

                Monitor.PulseAll(containers);

                return container;
            }
        }

        public static bool HeeftContainers()
        {
            lock (containers)
            {
                return containers.Any();
            }
        }
    }

public class Wagen
    {
        private Random random = new Random();

        public void VoerWerkzaamhedenUit()
        {
            while (Kade.HeeftContainers())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 6000));

                int container = Kade.VerwijderContainer();

                if (container != -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} heeft container nummer {1} van de kade gehaald.", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, container);

                    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1000, 6000));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And no, I do **not** want to use a blocking collection, I want to use a `List<int>` ;-)

Comment: You must live in Rotterdam.  The problem is that the wagen driver takes off and never comes back when the kade is empty.  You need a better exit condition, like a wagen back at the kade and the ship empty.  Also very strange for the driver to fall asleep when the kade has a container.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm from there. I think I see what you are getting at with the better exit condition, it's what Eren has said as well. I need to look better at your hint of the driver falling asleep though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the program starts, the trucks check the quay (`Kade.HeeftContainers()`) before the cranes get a chance to put containers on the quay so the truck threads exit right away. Then the cranes continue filling up the quay until it reaches the limit of 5 containers. Since the truck threads already exited, the quay stays full so crane threads stop waiting on `Monitor.Wait(containers);`.

To resolve the issue, the trucks need to keep running until all the containers have gone through the pipeline. For example, you can have a counter on the quay (e.g. `loadedContainers`) and increment this counter everytime a container is removed from the quay to be loaded on the trucks. Then `return loadedContainers == 100;` in the  `Kade.HeeftContainers` getter.

Comment: You are right! It was stupid of me that I didn't think about the fact that the truck threads could run before the crane threads, and thus exiting the while loop. What strikes me more is that this behavior is pretty consistent. I would've thought that in all of the times that I ran this program, on of those times the crane thread would've filled the containers on the quay so the a truck thread could work on it...

Comment: Right... So you are saying that because the quay is empty and the ship isn't, the preference for the program is to start out with the truck threads. That's interesting!

Comment: Never mind my earlier comment. I'll edit my answer to explain why you're consistently seeing the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Also learn about the Diagnostics namespace...

e.g.

```
if(!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Attach()) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```